# How to force dotnet core jwt authentication to not store key in ./AppData/Local/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys folder

Tags: .net-core, jwt, data-protection

**strong text**[Heap Screenshot of memory dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mum2S.png)I have implemented dotnet core jwt authentication in my dotnet core api and when I start my app a key file generated in  ./AppData/Local/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys path. I came to know that it is dataprotection key used by dotnet core to protect data and dotnet core by default read from that location and cache that keys in memory but the issue is that in production environment by time many keys are generated in that folder and dotnet core by default read this every 24 hrs and update cache accordingly. Due to huge amount of keys I am getting memmory leakage issue in LargObject portion of Garbage collection. Is is mandatory to store that keys? Is there anyway we can remove expired keys programatically?

Any help appriciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: how about [PersistKeysToDbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0#persistkeystodbcontext)

Comment: Hi Tiny, I have attached screenshot in that you can see large dictionary object which is related to dataprotection. I dont want to persist keys but I dont undesrstand how this large dictionary get generated. I dont have any data protection configuration in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own encryption key, and if you do that then ASP.NET Core does not need to create any data protection keys.

Having a key is important, because that key is used to encrypt and decrypt the ASP.NET Core session cookie.

I did blog about the data protection here that might help you:
[Storing the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault](https://www.edument.se/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault?lang=en)

However, the data protection API should not cause any memory leaks.

Comment: Hi Tore, Thanks for replying. I took memory dump and here isscreenshot for that. You can see large dictionary of KeyRing. I dont have manually configured data protection. We just use JWT authentication. SO just curious from where these large dictionary object generated.

Comment: I would investigate the debug logs from the DataProtectionAPI to investigate why its dictionary grows that much (set the debug level for the Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection namespace).  I would also see if I can persist the key-ring to a database instead of disk? you need to make sure keys/keyring is the same across deployments.